# Слайдер slick.js глючит на Firefox

Tags: slick.js

Слайдер slick.js плохо работает на Mozilla Firefox.
На других браузерах все работает правильно.
Не могу понять в чем проблема.
Интересным фактом является то, что на этой же странице есть еще один слайдер и он работает нормально.

Ссылка на сайт: http://takercorporation.com/

Comment: вы эту страницу сами слепили или заказывали ?

Comment: Данную страницу я делал сам.

Comment: + за красоту - но с адаптивностью воевать ещё вам

Comment: Там пока только десктоп для примера, данный сайт я только верстаю, это мой домен, а не клиента.